# Мой Python скрипт в Path

Tags: python, linux, windows, консоль, macos

Мне нужно чтобы мой Python файл (назовём его условно **PooMaker.py**), запускался через PATH.
То есть: чтобы я мог написать в командной строке Windows '>PooMaker' и скрипт запустился. Я искал информацию в интернете, но либо я не умею гуглить, либо этим вопросом никто не занимался.

Comment: Конвертируйте в exe и добавляйте в `PATH`.

Comment: Хороший совет выше дан. Используйте для этого Pyinstaller для этого. Установите, как им пользоваться есть куча информации в интернете.

Comment: Не обязательно конвертировать в exe, можно пусковой bat файл написать и добавить в path.